# Document-centric event scheduling on Azure

Tags: azure

I'm aware of the many different ways of scheduling *system*-centric events in Azure. E.g. Azure Scheduler, Logic Apps, etc. These can be used for things like backups, sending batch emails, or other maintenance functions.

However, I'm less clear on what technology is available for events relating to a large volume of *documents* or records.

For example, imagine I have 100,000 documents in Cosmos and some of the datetime properties on those documents relate to events: e.g. expiry, reminders, escalations, timeouts, etc. Each record has a different set of dates and times.

What approaches are there to fire off code whenever one of those datetimes is reached?

Stuff I've thought of so far:

1. Have a scheduled task that runs once per minute and looks for anything relating to that particular minute in Cosmos then does "stuff".
2. Schedule tasks on Service Bus queues with a future date as-and-when the Cosmos records are created and then have something to receive those messages and do "stuff".

But are there better ways of doing this? Is there a ready-made Azure service that would take away much of the background infrastructure work and just let me schedule a single one-off event at a particular point in time and hit a webhook or something like that?

Am I mis-categorising Azure Scheduler as something that you'd use for a handful of regularly scheduled tasks rather than the mixed bag of dates and times you'd find in 100,000 Cosmos records?

FWIW, in my use-case there isn't really a precision issue - stuff scheduled for 10:05:00 happening at 10:05:32 would be perfectly acceptable, for example.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Azure Schedular will be replaced by Azure Logic Apps:

> Azure Logic Apps is replacing Azure Scheduler, which is being retired. To schedule jobs, follow this article for moving to Azure Logic Apps instead.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps))

That said, Azure Logic Apps is one of your options since you can define a logic apps that starts a one time job by using a delay activity. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps#start-a-one-time-job) for details.

It scales very well and you can [pay for what you use (or use a fixed pricing model)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing).

Another option is using a durable azure function with a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers) in it. Once elapsed, you could do your thing. You can use a consumption plan as well, so you pay only for what you use or you can use a fixed pricing model. It also scales very well so hundreds of those instances won't be a problem.

In both cases you have to trigger the function or logic app when the Cosmos records are created. Put the due time as context in the trigger and there you go.

Now, given your statement

> I'm aware of the many different ways of scheduling system-centric events in Azure. E.g. Azure Scheduler, Logic Apps, etc. *These can be used for things like backups, sending batch emails, or other maintenance functions.*

That is up to you. You can do anything you want. You don't specify in your question  what work needs to be done when the due time is reached but I doubt it is something you can't do with those services.